# Float left and Float Right in Fixed <div> element

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header"> 

    <div class="image">
    image of page goes here
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
    Navigation of page goes here
    </div>

</div>


<div class="content">
<p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. 
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header {
 height: 10%;
 width: 80%;
 position: fixed;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.image {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
}

.navigation {
 float: right;
 width: 75%;
}

.content{
 padding-top: 8%;
}
```

With the above code I divide my webpage in a **fixed** header and a **scrollable** content. All this works fine so far. 
However, now I want that the `image` appears on the **left** side of the **header** whereas the `navigation` appears on the **right** side of the **header**. Therefore, I went with the properties `float: left;` and `float: right;`. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work becasue the `navigation` appears in the middle of the header.

What do I have to change in my code to get the `image` on the **left** side and the `navigation` on the **right** side?

You can also find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/q0yr6zsr/3/

Comment: Your code is correct now. The navigation is on the right but the copy is left aligned. So you can add elements inside of your 'navigation' div and float them right again. Remember to clear the floats afterwards. Read up on 'clearfix'

Comment: you could use a wrapper to solve that https://jsfiddle.net/q0yr6zsr/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use flex on the header and remove all floats. You will have more control on your content.

```css
.header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {}

.navigation {}

.content {
  padding-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    image of page goes here
  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    Navigation of page goes here
  </div>

</div>


<div class="content">
  <p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account
    brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty
    unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked
    large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other.
    Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no
    dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General
    enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between.
    No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart
    six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh.
    On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if
    am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving
    extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be
    females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing.
    Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove
    wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming.
    Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi hunzaboy, nice solution with the display: flex. What does the display: flex exactly do and how does it differ from float: right and float: left. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: @Michi, Flex is a display property just like block, inline-block, inline etc. You can read about it in detail here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

Your html and css are correct. The navigation is floated right. But your navigation element has a width of 75% of the header element. And the text of it is aligned left.

To show you how the navigation element is set just put a border around. Here is an example where i also shrink the width to 30%.

```
.navigation {
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use a flexbox and using `margin-left: auto` for the navigation.

```css
.header {
display: flex;
}

.navigation {
margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 

    <div class="image">
    image of page goes here
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
    Navigation of page goes here
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment. Nothing wrong with your code. I've added navigation elements in to the navigation tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/q0yr6zsr/5/

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
  <li>Contact us</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Home</li>
</ul>
</div>

.navigation ul li{
   width: 25%;
   float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've corrected the wrong width.

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="header"> 

    <div class="image">
    image of page goes here
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
    Navigation of page goes here
    </div>

</div>


<div class="content">
<p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. 
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.image {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}

.navigation {
 float: right;
 width: 35%;
}

.content{
 padding-top: 8%;
}
```